# Groovy syntax for grabbing build periodically property

Tags: jenkins, groovy, pipeline

I need to grab the "Build Triggers -> Build Periodically" values using a groovy script. I need to check if it is enabled and what the Schedule values are but I have no luck while searching through Jenkins' github and the javadoc.jenkins api documentation.

Comment: WorkflowJob.getTriggers() is a HashMap of kvps with the type of trigger as the key (in my case, 'Build Periodically') and the values as another data structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List keys = new ArrayList(job.getTriggers().keySet());

  for (int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++) {
   Object obj = keys.get(i);    
   if(obj.getDisplayName().contains("Build periodically")) {
      println job.fullName + "," + job.getTriggers().get(keys.get(i)).spec
   }
  }
```